# google map iso tile layer not work GMSTileURLConstructor GMSURLTileLayer

Tags: ios, google-maps

GMSTileURLConstructor GMSURLTileLayer not showing tiles

I am trying to overlay my own tiles( tilestream) on top of google map. 
But it failed. So I decide to try overlay openstreet map tiles on top of google map,  because the tile URL for tilestream is same structure as URL for openstreet map. Both are http://xxx/z/x/y.png

use GMSTileURLConstructor GMSURLTileLayer, but failed showing tiles

Only google SDKdemo sample works fine.
the url is :

```
 NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.gstatic.com/io2010maps/tiles/9/L1_%tu_%tu_%tu.png",zoom, x, y];
```

if I use openstreet URL, it failed to display custom tiles at any zoom level.

```
 NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%tu/%tu/%tu.png", (unsigned long)zoom, (unsigned long)x, (unsigned long)y];
```

zIndex set to 99, 100, 1, still not showing tiles.

I confirm the tile server works fine, the tile image is correctly received if I directly use url in browser.

also google sample floor plan tile, zoom, x, y exactly match openstreet map zoom, x, y.

I don't understand, why google sample tile URL works fine, but openstreet map url tiles DOSE NOT showing.

here is my code: anyone know why?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


//------------- google map ------------

//    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:33.6599244
//                                                            longitude:-117.915058135
//                                                                 zoom:13];

   GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:37.78318
                                                            longitude:-122.403874
                                                                 zoom:18];




mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
//mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;
mapView_.buildingsEnabled = NO;
mapView_.indoorEnabled = NO;

self.view = mapView_;




// Create a new GMSTileLayer with the new floor choice.
GMSTileURLConstructor urls = ^(NSUInteger x, NSUInteger y, NSUInteger zoom) {

    //NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.gstatic.com/io2010maps/tiles/9/L1_%tu_%tu_%tu.png",zoom, x, y];



     //NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/%tu/%tu/%tu.png", zoom, x, y];
     NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%tu/%tu/%tu.png", (unsigned long)zoom, (unsigned long)x, (unsigned long)y];

    NSLog(@"%@", url);
    return [NSURL URLWithString:url];
};
layer = [GMSURLTileLayer tileLayerWithURLConstructor:urls];


layer.zIndex = 1;
layer.opacity= 0.5;

layer.map = mapView_;
```

Comment: Is this on android?

Comment: no, it is on ios iphone

Comment: How to get x and y?

Answer (score 4):

after 10 hours try and failed, I finally found why?

It is because security setting block from downloading any tiles images, json, anything from remote server.

The error message on console is:

The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection

the solution is:

1. Opened my Projects info.plist file(as source)
2. add key

   ```
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
       <true/>
       <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
       <dict>
           <key>yourdomain.com</key>
           <dict>
               <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
               <true/>
               <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
               <false/>
           </dict>
      </dict>
   ```

Now it works, i successfully overlay openstreet map on top of google map, and I also can overlay any custom tile from any tile server on top of google map.

Where `yourdomain.com` is for example `http://b.tile.opentopomap.org` (in case of OSM topo map). You have to add a key for every http provider.